# Spring security login can't find view and get Resource not found HTTP 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am working on a little **Spring boot** project. I have setted up a spring security config to enable **h2console**, *public endpoints*..

I can access to this public endpoints. Anyway when I try access to /admin/login I a get an **404 HTTP** error and this message in the console log:

```
2023-05-23T18:01:07.248+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/admin/login", parameters={}
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.248+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.249+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resource not found
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.249+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.250+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.250+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.250+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.250+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.250+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.250+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.251+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using 'application/json', given [image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.251+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Writing [{timestamp=Tue May 23 18:01:07 CEST 2023, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available, (truncated)...]
[2m2023-05-23T18:01:07.251+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m21672[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

This is my **spring security http config**:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                authorize
                
                    .requestMatchers(
                        PathRequest.toH2Console()
                    ).permitAll()
                        
                    .requestMatchers(
                        "/api/auth/login",
                        "/api/auth/logout",
                        "/admin/login",
                        "/error"
                    ).permitAll()
                
            ).formLogin((formLogin) ->
                formLogin
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginPage("/admin/login")
                    .failureUrl("/admin/login?failed")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/login/process")
                    .permitAll()
                    
            ).logout((logout) ->
                logout
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutUrl("/api/auth/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")
                    
            ).headers((headers) ->
                headers
                    .frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions.sameOrigin())
            )
        ;
        return http.build();
}
```

I tested putting my "**admin/login.html**" in "**/resources, /resources/static and /resources/templates**" (like console log show) but continue not working in any of this directories.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create valid mapping to selected path, i assume you are using thymeleaf as template engine, in order to work, in your REST controller create a mapping for example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/admin/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
```

"YourHtmlLoginFileName" is the name of the file in your /resources/templates whithout extension.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `contextPath` key in your configuration file (e.g. application.properties or application.yml). If you have this param, you have to add `/{contextPath.value}` before your requets.